# How can I send a big HTML block in JSON

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, json, encoding

I need to send a big block of HTML in a Json object like this:

```
                JsonResult jsn =  Json(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "success", true }, 
            { "lastPID", posts[0].ID }, 
            { "content", "" } });
            return jsn;
```

For some reason I get this error when I put that html block into the content variable: Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent.

This doesn't happen if I return some random non-html content.

Is there any encoding that I need to do before I can send my big block of html?

What about the client end? How do I get back the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748428/partialview-as-string-jsonresult) is your problem (and solution)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send HTML, why not *just* send HTML rather than JSON?

Comment: Because I also need to send some other data 'lastPID' in the same result. It's very important that I send the lastPId.

Comment: One way is to have a javascript function inside the send html that sets the id. If you render the hmtl this function can get called  (ie by $(document).ready)